# Laravel 5 Use global helper or include the Facade

Tags: performance, laravel-5

To check if the user is logged in, for example. I can use global helper `auth()`:

```
if (auth()->check()) {
  //...
}
```

But I can also use the Auth facade:

Include it in the top:
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`

And then

```
if (Auth::check()) {
   //...
}
```

The former is a quicker way, but the latter seems clearer.

Is there any performance difference between the two ?